# How to use Touch ID as an alternative for iOS app user authentication?

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-id

I'm planing to integrate Touch ID into my app and use it as an alternative to username & password authentication. Here is my though for the process:

**First time:** Login by username & password -> enable Touch ID -> receive an access key from server.
**Second time** (with Touch ID enabled): Touch ID authentication success -> directly access server by access ID.

So, securing access key is vital here. Besides Apple's data protection APIs (which offers no protection if user's device is unlocked), is there any better way to protect it?

Also, is this the correct way to utilize Touch ID?

Comment: This is a common scenario! And a correct way to utilize touch ID and will secure access key.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this will be helpful or not but you could store the username and password in Apple's keychain upon success.  Then once the touch Id is authenticated the second time you can grab the username and password from keychain (Make sure to check if it stills exists) and attempt a login. Or I believe you could store the access key there instead of username and password.